# How to update or manage Annotated Time Line chart through google spreadsheet app's custom code?

Tags: google-visualization, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am working on a spreadsheet of me at google spreadsheet. [You can visit it here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At2D9TJiKMY3dDlfRDhGY1I0R1dIX2NvOVFST0w0LWc#gid=3).

If you visit the page you will see 2 charts at the current sheet (Graph Input). The first one is the embedded one and the last or below one is the `"Annotated Time Line"`. Now, I have got a script (by googling) to automatically update the chart whenever the spreadsheet's rows are edited. By adding and submitting inputs to [this form](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dDlfRDhGY1I0R1dIX2NvOVFST0w0LWc6MA#gid=3) you can add some data/row to the spreadsheet. The inputs will be automatically added to the spreadsheet.

Now when i trigger or run the script **(`onEdit` function)** then only the first or top chart is getting updated. But the 2nd or below one is not updating.

Here is the code:

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var c = s.getCharts();

  for (var i in c) {
    var ch = c[i];
    var ranges = ch.getRanges();
    var mod = ch.modify();
    for (var j in ranges) {
      var range = ranges[j];
      mod.removeRange(range);
      var newRange = expandRange_(range);
      mod.addRange(newRange);
    }
    s.updateChart(mod.build());
  }
}

function rangeShouldExpand_(range) {
  var s = range.getSheet();
  var numCol = range.getNumColumns()
  var values = s.getSheetValues(range.getLastRow(), range.getColumn(), 2, numCol);

  for (var i = 0; i < numCol; i++) {
    if (!values[0][i] && !values[1][i] || !!values[0][i] && !!values[1][i]) {
      continue;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function expandRange_(range) {
  var s = range.getSheet()
  var startRow = range.getRow();
  var startCol = range.getColumn();
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var numCols = range.getNumColumns();
  while (rangeShouldExpand_(range)) {
    numRows++;
    range = s.getRange(startRow, startCol, numRows, numCols);
  }
  return range;
}
```

Now, what should i do or what changes should i make to get the both charts working?

Thanks,
Omar Sharif

Comment: Your script returns `ReferenceError: "chart" is not defined. (line 13)`  I guess the copy you shared is missing some parts ...

Comment: I have changed the missing parts at the code. I mistakenly wrote `chart` instead of `ch` at line `13 and 14`. @Serge insas

Comment: thx, I tested here, all charts are being updated when i change something on sheet1... Did I misunderstood your question when I thought it didn't work ?

Comment: all charts means? the `Annotated Time Line Chart` also working with this code? @Serge insas

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the embedded charts functionality currently only works on an undocumented subset of all the available charts, which may not include the Time Line Chart type. You can file a feature request to better document this functionality on our [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

Answer (score 0):

Your script seems to work as it is designed for, meaning the charts are updated '`on edit`', meaning when a user accesses the sheet. If you wich it gets updated on form submission without any other user action then I'd suggest to add an '`on form submit`' trigger to call your updating function using the spreadsheet ressource panel.

From what I see on the copy I made of your spreadsheet all the charts are processed when the function is called.

Comment: I have tried you. But it's not working on the `"Time Line"` chart. Can you please describe a little more about your process? Or do you have any example? @Serge insas